# How to set port for Next js on PM2

Tags: node.js, service, next.js, pm2

i have an ordinary next js application with the following scripts in my package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3002"
  },
```

I have a start script with the `-p` tag to start the application on port 3002.

I hope to run this application using `pm2` with the following script.

```
PORT=3002 NODE_PORT=3002 pm2 start npm --name "nextjs-website" -- start
```

Using the env variables PORT and NODE_PORT don't work. How do i start this application using the same port as mentioned in the package.json file.

Also is it possible to run the pm2 service the run the `start` in the package.json file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In package.json add this start script "start": "next start -p 8000" and then use PM2 to start it with

```
pm2 start yarn --name "nextjs" --interpreter bash -- start
pm2 show nextjs
```

check this article for more details. https://www.willandskill.se/en/setup-a-next-js-project-with-pm2-nginx-and-yarn-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 16):

Setting port number in npm script is not good idea at all.

Use this command to start server at any port

> sudo pm2 start npm --name "dev-staging" -- run start -- --port=8000

or use an alias

> sudo pm2 start npm --name "dev-staging" -- run start -- -p 8000